# Image weirdness with slick2d graphics translation

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I am making a game and I noticed whenever I use the graphics.translate function and after the translate this happens to the images.

Before Translation
[image: Before translation]

After Translation
[image: After Translation]

I was wondering if there is anyway to fix that or anyone else has the same issue. All these sprites are rendered from a spritesheet

EDIT: Translate code

```
public void translate(Graphics g, GameContainer container, int delta) {
        g.translate(((container.getWidth() / 2) - this.x), ((container.getHeight() / 2) - this.y));
    }

    public void update(GameContainer container, int type){
        if (type == 0) {
            x = p.getX(); //p is the player
            y = p.getY();
        } else if (type == 1) {
            x = player.x;
            y = player.y;
        }

        if (offset) {
            if (this.x - container.getWidth() / 2 < offsetMin[0]) {
                x = offsetMin[0] + container.getWidth() / 2;
            } else if (this.x + container.getWidth() / 2 > offsetMax[0]) {
                x = offsetMax[0] - container.getWidth() / 2;
            }

            if (this.y - container.getHeight() / 2 < offsetMin[1]) {
                y = offsetMin[1] + container.getHeight() / 2;
            } else if (this.y + container.getHeight() > offsetMax[1]) {
                y = offsetMax[1] - container.getHeight() / 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May we see where you do the translation and rendering? I have never seen an x/y translation resize drawn objects like that.

Comment: @CConard96 Edited, did you just want the translate code or the rendering aswell.. It seems to just be when the graphics gets translated

Comment: Does it help if you cast the x and y parameters for g.translate() to ints? That would eliminate any rounding errors where tiles don't end up on perfect pixel coords (IE 4, not 4.2). The other thing to check is that interpolation is set for nearest neighbor and not linear. Linear interpolation can pull in surrounding colors.

Comment: How would I check the interpolation? @CConard96

Comment: GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
      GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST); This code goes in your render loop to set it to nearest neighbor.

Comment: Thank you, casting it as an int worked. Thank you very much! @CConard96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the x and y parameters for g.translate() to ints. That would eliminate any rounding errors where tiles don't end up on perfect pixel coords (IE 4, not 4.2).

*Moved answer from comments to answer so it can be marked as accepted by OP*